# Freeradius server for multiple vendor network

Tags: linux, configuration, radius

We have been using network switches from Enterasys and for logging in to these switches, with AD credentials, we have setup a freeradius server on RHEL 6.5 server, that is working absolutely fine.

The `/etc/raddb/users` file is as below:

```
DOMAIN_USER1     Auth-Type := ntlm_auth
                 Filter-id = "Enterasys:version=1:mgmt=su"

DOMAIN_USER2     Auth-Type := ntlm_auth
                 Filter-id = "Enterasys:version=1:mgmt=su"

USER1            Cleartext-password := PASSWORD
                 Filter-id = "Enterasys:version=1:mgmt=ro"
```

Now, switches from different vendors like HP and Extreme networks are introduced in our network environment. With above mentioned attributes, logging in to the HP and Extreme switches is possible, but just as a read-only user (which, I suppose, is due to improper attributes set).

In order to deal with this, I've added another user `USER2`, in order to log in to Extreme switches with admin rights, in the `/etc/raddb/users` file as below:

```
USER2           User-password := PASSWORD
                Service-Type = "Administrative-User",
                Filter-Id = "unlim"
```

With this, user `USER2` is able to log in to the Extreme switch with admin rights.

How should I proceed if I want to have single user account in order to log in to all the switches with admin privileges? How can I apply multiple attributes to single user?